# Generate VB.NET Code to Run SSIS Package?

Tags: vb.net, ssis, dts

I'm a systems programmer myself and completely new to DTS or any ETL etc. I have a situation here and would greatly appreciate your support.

we are using MS SQL 2000 till now in project and now efforts are on way to move to 2008.

I can see some .dts files which were created long back with MSSQL2000. VB script(.bas) files were generated from these .dts files and they are run in the VB program, till date.

Problem::
Now as we are moving to MS SQL 2008 ==> 
I need to make sure that the VB program(generated from .dts files earlier) are good to be run and MAINTAINED even with MSSQL 2008 R2.

Question:
Firstly can these programs be maintained even in MSSQL2008 (without MSSQL2000) ?
If yes, do i need to any dll's or references etc?

I could see one of my team member migrating the .dts to .dtsx files, is there a way to generate VB files(.bas) from .dtsx ?

Answer (score 1):

ETL solutions in SQL Server 2000 (DTS) and SQL Server 2008 (SSIS) are incompatible, but you could use [Execute DTS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137907%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) task from SSIS package. You don't need any dll's for it.

That'll give you some time before you have a chance to rewrite your system. You'll have to do it eventually, because 'Execute DTS' is deprecated component and won't be supported in future versions.

Comment: Thanks Arya for info. 

Right now I'm migrating these .dts packages to .dtsx (using MS BI tool) and then trying to run the .dtsx files from VB code (as the program still is in VB (not .net) ).

But i'm facing challenge to pass the variables while doing this.
I mean to have placeholders(variables) in .dtsx files and pass them while executing in VB (for example the sever name, infile, outfile paths etc)
Would greatly appreciate if you can give me any info/ways regarding passing arguements/variables while executing .dtsx (in VB)
or even example to run the .dtsx from VB
Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: I guess, from native VB, the easiest would be to use DTExec utility. Start [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162810(v=sql.105).aspx).